# How to add Dropdown arrow to a <li> which has child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

This is my original menu.

```html
<ul class="mymenu">
<li><a href="#">1 HTML </a></li>
<li><a href="#">2 CSS</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">3.1 jQuery </a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">3.1.1 Download</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3.1.2 Tutorial</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">3 Javascript </a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to convert it into

```html
<ul class="mymenu">
<li><a href="#">1 HTML </a></li>
<li><a href="#">2 CSS <span class="parent">&#9660</span></a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">3.1 jQuery </a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">3.1.1 Download</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3.1.2 Tutorial</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">3 Javascript </a></li>
</ul>
```

The difference between two menu is,

```html
<span class="parent">&#9660</span>
```

I want to add dropdown arrow to the each element which has submenu.

I want Jquery or javascript solution.

Comment: Have you made an effort to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: You need JS or CSS solution?

Comment: Should 3.1 jQuery also get the arrow? It has a submenu but your example doesn't include it. If you did try anything please post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will provide two solutions to the problem.

**1).** Javascript solution. Using jQuery you can achieve it pretty easy:

```
$('a + ul').prev('a').append('<span class="parent">&#9660</span>');
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/37k1KMpqJ6G2tPrvprBa?p=preview

**2).** CSS only solution. Using modern pseudo selectors you can do this:

```
li a:not(:only-child):after {
    content: '\25bc';
}
```

Additional info: [`:only-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child) and [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selectors. Support: IE9+.

Note: CSS solution is not equivalent to javascript one, as it doesn't insert `span.parent` element in DOM.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/sfoctCWzjRCBlXG9dVyD?p=preview